# Convert a string of HTML into DOM objects with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have HTML in a JavaScript string (containing usual, nested HTML). Using jQuery, can I convert that into a valid HTML element in a single stroke using any of the `document.create`* functions? My requirement is to use `document.getElementById` on the created DOM object.

Comment: HTML should never be in a string in JavaScript.

Comment: @Raynos: That's not very true.  What if you get some pre-rendered HTML from the server?

Comment: Please edit your question to acknowledge that you are using a convenience library like jQuery. I spent unnecessary time writing native JavaScript code.

Comment: @SLaks I agree it's not completely true. What is true however, is HTML should never be in a string in JavaScript _application_ code. It's acceptable as a hidden layer in a library.

Comment: @Raynos: You mean that HTML strings should never explicitly appear in Javascript source code.  Yes.

Comment: @SLaks Why are you getting pre-rendered html from the server to begin with?

Comment: @Zirak: Because it's easier than client-side templating.  eg, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8631515/34397

Comment: @SLaks HTML string _literals_ are banned from javascript source code. Strings containing actual HTML should be avoided like the plague, there are edge cases like using them in a library, having HTML as user input or debugging.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take simple nested example.

```
var dom_string = '<div>xxx<div>yyy</div></div>';
```

create HTML DOM elements using $() function of jquery and append wherever you want. 
i have taken 'body' but you can append anywhere.

```
$(dom_string).appendTo('body');
```

Alternatively you can implement this with pure javascript:

```
var dom_target = document.getElementById("target");
dom_target.innerHTML = dom_string;
```

Comment: Try to avoid using jQuery when it's not asked for, it's just confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Create a dummy element and set its `innerHTML` to your HTML string.

Comment: Thanks. May I know on what elements can I invoke getElementById apart from on document object.

Comment: after setting innerHTML, your DOM part of string behave as real DOM elements so you can apply getElementById on every nested tag of string,

Answer (score 4):

```
// Construct a container as a placeholder for your content

var container = document.createElement('div');
container.id = 'container';

// Inject the container into the DOM

document.body.appendChild(container);

// Populate the injected container with your content

container.innerHtml = '<p id="pTag">I am a <em>P</em> tag with some <strong>nested markup</strong>.</p>';
```

Answer (score 4):

To convert Html text into a Jquery-Object use the $() function:

```
div = '<div>hello world</div>';
$div = $(div);
```

But as others have noted in most cases you don't need that because DOM manipulation functions like append() and prepend() will accept plain text, so

```
$('body').append('<div>hello world</div>');
```

is absolutely fine.